# Infinite Loop Issue with RSS Feed

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, power-automate, rss, duplicate

What's the deal? I am a novice user of Power Automate, trying to keep an RSS feed on SharePoint through a List web part. Had a developer put this together today and then peace out on me with no reply since. Everything is working as intended except when it refreshes every hour, it creates a listing regardless of what's already there. Hopefully this is a simple ask, what conditions am I overlooking?

[image]